# cyclic dependency detected error with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a schema for 'Socket' model, when I try to save any created socket object in mongoose, it gives me the vague error `Error: cyclic dependency detected` marking only node_modules and none of my files. The schema code is as below. The way I save the socket object is also as under. Please point out the mistake if possible.

socket.js file

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const SocketSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    socket_object: Schema.Types.Mixed,
    socket_id: Schema.Types.Mixed,

// other model links
    room_link: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Room' },
})

SocketSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    this.socket_id = this.socket_object.id;
    next();
});

// SocketSchema.set('autoIndex', false);

mongoose.model('Socket', SocketSchema);
```

How I am saving the socket object:

```
let newSocket = new Socket({
    _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
    socket_object: socket,
});      

console.log('-----------------NEW SOCKET---------------')
console.log(newSocket)

newSocket.save(function(err, newSocket){
    if (err) {
        console.log('--------------------LOG SOCKET NOT SAVED------------------------')
        return console.log(err)
    }
})
```

As soon as I run above code, I get the bottom vague error

> Error: cyclic dependency detected
> at serializeObject (/home/arsalan/Work_stuff/Full_stack_apps/NATIVE_APPS/webRTC_fresh/webRTC_fullstack/web/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:333:34)
> at serializeInto (/home/arsalan/Work_stuff/Full_stack_apps/NATIVE_APPS/webRTC_fresh/webRTC_fullstack/web/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:941:17)
> at serializeObject (/home/arsalan/Work_stuff/Full_stack_apps/NATIVE_APPS/webRTC_fresh/webRTC_fullstack/web/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:347:18)
> at serializeInto (/home/arsalan/Work_stuff/Full_stack_apps/NATIVE_APPS/webRTC_fresh/webRTC_fullstack/web/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:941:17)
> at serializeObject (/home/arsalan/Work_stuff/Full_stack_apps/NATIVE_APPS/webRTC_fresh/webRTC_fullstack/web/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:347:18)
> at serializeInto (/home/arsalan/Work_stuff/Full_stack_apps/NATIVE_APPS/webRTC_fresh/webRTC_fullstack/web/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:941:17)
> at serializeObject (/home/arsalan/Work_stuff/Full_stack_apps/NATIVE_APPS/webRTC_fresh/webRTC_fullstack/web/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:347:18)
> at serializeInto (/home/arsalan/Work_stuff/Full_stack_apps/NATIVE_APPS/webRTC_fresh/webRTC_fullstack/web/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:941:17)
> at serializeObject (/home/arsalan/Work_stuff/Full_stack_apps/NATIVE_APPS/webRTC_fresh/webRTC_fullstack/web/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:347:18)
> at serializeInto (/home/arsalan/Work_stuff/Full_stack_apps/NATIVE_APPS/webRTC_fresh/webRTC_fullstack/web/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:941:17)
> at serializeObject (/home/arsalan/Work_stuff/Full_stack_apps/NATIVE_APPS/webRTC_fresh/webRTC_fullstack/web/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:347:18)
> at serializeInto (/home/arsalan/Work_stuff/Full_stack_apps/NATIVE_APPS/webRTC_fresh/webRTC_fullstack/web/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:941:17)
> at serializeObject (/home/arsalan/Work_stuff/Full_stack_apps/NATIVE_APPS/webRTC_fresh/webRTC_fullstack/web/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:347:18)
> at serializeInto (/home/arsalan/Work_stuff/Full_stack_apps/NATIVE_APPS/webRTC_fresh/webRTC_fullstack/web/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:727:17)
> at serializeObject (/home/arsalan/Work_stuff/Full_stack_apps/NATIVE_APPS/webRTC_fresh/webRTC_fullstack/web/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:347:18)
> at serializeInto (/home/arsalan/Work_stuff/Full_stack_apps/NATIVE_APPS/webRTC_fresh/webRTC_fullstack/web/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:941:17)

please point out the mistake if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `Socket` object is a system object. It provides access to underlying networking capabilities provided by the host operating system.

You are trying to save that to your db. You Can't Do That™. Your object contains state -- the state of the connection to another machine in the case of TCP sockets -- that simply can't be restored if you try to retrieve the saved object later. If you want to use a similar socket later, you'll have to reconstruct it.

And, those sorts of system objects have sub-objects that point to each other. That's what makes them circular. That makes them more efficient. Serialization works best with data structures that are [directed acyclic graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph).

I've needed similar functionality for a websocket-based app. I provided it with a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) of socket objects, to keep track of them in RAM. Upon opening a socket, I did `socketSet.add(socket)`. And upon deleting it I did `socketSet.delete(socket)`. And, when I needed to see all the open sockets I used `socketSet.foreach()`.

Socket.io provides ways to emit [messages to whole rooms](https://socket.io/docs/rooms/) or to individual connections as well.

Comment: So what do you suggest ? Should I keep sockets in the RAM? I am creating chat app like WhatsApp so any suggestions for such situation? I understand that I can't save this object into my DB but please give me some way out. Thanks

Comment: What do you want to do by saving Socket objects to your database? What do you hope to do with them when you retrieve them? Because saving Sockets makes no sense in nodejs (or in any TCP/IP app anywhere), it's difficult to guess what you're trying to do from your sample code.

Comment: If you are already working with connections, you can store it in redis
there is a library to store sessions in redis that can do it for you

Comment: My goal was to save the sockets for users in a room, so that I can call socket.emit on them. Let me check redis

Comment: I have checked out redis, can you point out what specific library stores sessions in redis ?

Comment: Umm, `redis-sessions`? https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis-sessions